# How to set a path font in a ubuntu server wihtout GUI?

Tags: command-line, fonts

I've been searching how to do this and all awnsers that I can find are using some kind of UI. I'm pretty sure that is a way to do this just by some commands but I couldn't find it yet.

What i did so far,
I managed to download & unzip the font that I want.. With this script:

```bash
#/bin/bash
wget https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/releases/download/v2.1.0/DroidSansMono.zip
mkdir -p ~/.fonts
unzip DroidSansMono.zip -d ~/.fonts
fc-cache -fv
echo "done!
```

The font seems to be found and all good there..

Now, How can i tell to the Terminal to use this Font?

PS: I don't have an GUI installed and I don't want to install one just to set a font.

Comment: The terminal takes fonts as available and set on the client machine, not on the server machine.

Comment: hmm.. okay, I'll check in client side now..

Comment: yeah that works now.. I had to download, install and ser the patched font in the client that in this case was windows. thanks @vanadium

Comment: Since the client here is Windows, this has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: @bySamo What do you mean "the client is windows"? Are you using WSL?

Comment: No no it's not a WSL, I use SSH from a bash terminal in windows.